# jquery-bootgrid Styling Issue

Tags: jquery-bootgrid

jquery-bootgrid is a great little tool, i have it working perfectly well functionally, but i have an issue with the styling of the control.

For some reason the search bar generated by the js library spans across the entirepage, forcing the control for selecting the number of results shown, down to a new line.

I've also noticed that the paging control isn't styled correctly and nor is the dropdown for removing columns.

I've got the latest css and js files, is anybody else having the same issue?

I have the latest bootstrap available, could this be an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I didn't include the jquery.bootgrid.css in my bundling at the right spot.